# Power BI Measure to calculate sum of hours based ID, type, and date

Tags: powerbi, dax

Could use some help figuring out a Power BI measure.

I have a list of projects by ID.
Projects have estimated hours categorized as Original Estimates and Revised Estimates.
Revised Estimates have a Revision Date

```
+------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+
| Project ID |    Hours    |    HoursType     | RevisionDate |
+------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+
|          1 | 100         | OriginalEstimate |              |
|          2 | 50          | OriginalEstimate |              |
|          3 | 200         | OriginalEstimate |              |
|          4 | 60          | OriginalEstimate |              |
|          2 | 200         | RevisedEstimate  | 1/1/2020     |
|          5 | 200         | OriginalEstimate |              |
|          3 | 100         | RevisedEstimate  | 2/1/2020     |
|          6 | 80          | OriginalEstimate |              |
|          2 | 250         | RevisedEstimate  | 3/1/2020     |
|            |             |                  |              |
|            |             |                  |              |
|            | Total = 790 |                  |              |
+------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+
```

If there is a RevisedEstimate, the sum should ignore the OriginalEstimate for that Project ID and use the RevisedEstimate with that latest RevisionDate.

I've read through a number of sites on the different DAX functions, and I can't quite find something that will achieve this outcome.

So far I can only get two variables at a time to work. For instance, summing the hours based on Project ID and the HoursType (meaning all hours for Original Estimates or all hours for Revised Estimates).  And I can pull the last revision date and hours, but not by ID (so in my example I only get the hours for 3/1/2020).

I have seen a couple posts suggesting that maybe there isn't a way to do this from a measure or that I'd have to create more tables.  I've been trying to solve it in a way that doesn't require creating more tables...maybe that is the only way?

If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will call you table "Data".

```
Project Hours =
VAR Latest_Dates =
    SUMMARIZE ( Data, Data[Project ID], "Last Date", MAX ( Data[RevisionDate] ) )
VAR Latest_Hours =
    TREATAS ( Last_Dates, Data[Project ID], Data[RevisionDate] )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Data[Hours] ), Latest_Hours )
RETURN
    Result
```

If you put this measure into a matrix visual, you will get:

[image]

How it works:

1. We group your data by project ID, and for each of them find the latest (max) revision date (if there are no revisions, it's just blank). We save the results into a variable "Latest_Dates".
2. We use the saved table to filter the original table, and save results into another variable - "Latest Hours". It will now contain only those records where revision date is the latest.
3. Finally, we sum the hours only for the records that we have in "Latest_Hours" table.

You can learn more about this pattern here:
 https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/propagate-filters-using-treatas-in-dax/

Comment: Many thanks RADO!  Was trying to figure out how to use SUMMARIZE properly.  Your explanation cleared that up.  I hadn't looked at TREATAS before, so I have something new to research.  And that link is awesome too.  Will be spending some time this weekend studying that.  Pretty sure I have a number of uses for propagated filters.  :-)  Thanks very much for your help.